# Android Map Fragment inside MainActivity doesn't call onMapReady

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-fragments

I made a map FragmentActivity and I want to display it in MainActivity so I can have other elements in the activity.

When I run the app the map starts, but it doesn't fire the onMapReady, hence it's just a basic map in which I cannot move put markers or move the camera programmatically.

The code is really basic, I just put the map in the MainActivity XML.

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:id="@+id/map"
              android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:layout_weight="4"
              tools:context="com.crisser.beitnaonline.MapsActivity"/>
```

Any idea why it doesn't work?

**MainActivity code:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
OnMapReadyCallback
{

private FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
private DatabaseReference firebaseRef;
private GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() == null)
    {
        goLoginScreen();
    }

    firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    firebaseRef = firebaseDatabase.getReference().child("event");
    firebaseRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
        {
            for (DataSnapshot event : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
            {
                Log.i("event", event.toString());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError)
        {

        }
    });



}

private void goLoginScreen()
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | 
    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | 
            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
}

public void logout(View view)
{
    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
    LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
    goLoginScreen();
}


@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)
{
    Log.e("fired", "fired");
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 15);
    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("test"));
    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
}
```

**MapsActivity code:**

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements 
OnMapReadyCallback
{

private GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready 
    to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) 
    getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}


/**
 * Manipulates the map once available.
 * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the 
   camera. In this case,
 * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
 * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be 
   prompted to install
 * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once 
   the user has
 * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
 */
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)
{
    mMap = googleMap;
    Log.e("fired", "fired");
    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 15);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("test"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can this;

Please try inside framelayout, like this;

```
    <FrameLayout ...>
    <fragment 
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.blabla"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Well, I didn't post the entire XML, but it is inside a RelativeLayout already, still doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Change

// Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.

```
 SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) 
getSupportFragmentManager()
        .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
```

to

```
SupportMapFragment mapFragment = ((SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.safety_map));
```

I expected, it will work perfectly. Best of luck!

Comment: Please try it. it will help you.

Comment: sorry, I was out for the weekend. 2 questions tho:

1. how do I get the "getChildFragmentManager()" method? it doesn't seem to be a default one.

2. What is safety_map? do I create another fragment?

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement your activity by "OnMapReadyCallback.
Then you will be able to fire onMapReady call back method.

Comment: If you mean to implement OnMapReadyCallback in the MainActivity and put the code there I did that and it still didn't work.

Comment: You have to use a code like this.
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
}
Your activity should extends FragmentActivity instead of AppCompatActivity.

Comment: I have the OnMapReadyCallback in the MapsActivity too and it fires when I start it as an activity, but when I put the fragment in another activity it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

To get onMapReady call back you need to use below code in activity's onCreate().

```
SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
```

Comment: yup, I got that too, as I said, it works when I start it as an activity. I just created the map activity from android studio, it implemented everything

Answer (score 0):

Sir, maybe you are missing this dependency in the "build.gradle (Module:app)":

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you, the question was posted 2 years ago, I cannot remember how exactly I fixed it since I am not working on that project anymore, but your answer might help others who are having this problem.